# Using conditional formatting for counting days in an Excel Gantt chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I really need some help with a Excel formula that I am using for a Gantt chart.

Currently I can enter a start date and the number of days I want the task to run. The sheet then calculates an end date. However, my sheet only shows work days, not weekends, and so when I put 6 days of work in to start on a Monday the end date is given on the Saturday, not the following Monday.

I am using the following formula to calculate the end date:
=IF(AND(F6,G6),G6+F6-1,"") where F6 is the number of days for the task, and G6 is the start date.

Thanks,

C.

Answer (score 3):

There is [`WORKDAY`](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/WORKDAY-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33) for that.
Be aware that you have to subtract 1: to start with a Monday (say, 7/6/15) in cell A1, and get the following Monday as the day "x days after" with `x=6` the value in cell B1, you have to use

```
=WORKDAY(A1,B1-1)
```